# brand new nexus 5 boot animation loop

Tags: boot-loop, nexus-5

This has happened to me with other phones after messing with ROMs and stuff - but this is a real bummer: I just got it out of the box for the first time, turned it on, and it's stuck on the animation loop.

Any ideas what I can do? I'll try reaching Google for support but I'm not in the country where it was purchased and it's a little urgent so I'm trying here as well).

P.S. only relevant information I can think of: it has been lying in its box for almost a month since I bought it.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried reset your phone in recovery mode?

Nexus 5

- If your phone is on, turn it off.
- Press & hold the Volume Down and Volume Up buttons, and then press & hold the Power button simultaneously until the phone turns on. You'll see the word "Start" with an arrow drawn around it.
- Press the Volume Down button twice to highlight Recovery mode.
- Press the Power button to start Recovery mode. You'll see an image of an Android robot with a red exclamation mark.
- While holding the Power button, press the Volume Up button.
- Use the volume buttons to scroll to "wipe data / factory reset" and press the Power button to select it.
- Scroll down to "Yes – erase all user data" and press the Power button to select it.

Note: If at any point during the above steps your phone becomes unresponsive, you can restart it by holding down the power button for several seconds.

https://support.google.com/nexus/answer/4596836?hl=en-GB